# How to make jetty buffer all request body before invoke servlet

Tags: jetty

My application has very high CPU load average, the reason is jetty start lots of thread to handle request, and may block on data, when data ready, lots of thread become runnable. I want to make jetty wait until all data read, and then start thread to invoke servlet, in that case servlet will never be blocked.

Is is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible.

Jetty needs a thread to either read the request content body itself (for things like mime multitpart, form parameters, etc), or to use that thread to dispatch to your webapp for your Servlet to read the request content body.

Then there is the added ability of Async I/O (introduced in Servlet 3.1) that allows you to write a Servlet that only uses a thread when it can either read or write to the socket, letting the thread fall back to the ThreadPool if neither can be done.

Comment: I suppose, jetty should be able to use one thread to handle many connections with NIO

Comment: If using Servlets, you will be using Async I/O, you have no access to the NIO layers within Jetty.

Comment: yes, I know I cannot do it, only jetty core can acess NIO. Anyway, thanks!